# CoreLocation - CLLocation.speed always -1 on iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, core-location

CLLocationManager.location.speed return always -1 but latitude and longitude are set and "real".

Same code works on iOS6.

Also the Apple example project LocateMe 
https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html
doesn't work in iOS7: no speed and no heading in CLLocationManager.location object.

Have anyone this problem?

Comment: I've noted that this happens changing the CLLocationManager.delegate (from one object to another or to nil). Solution: I've wrapped the CLLocationManager with a new Object. The wrapper is always the CLLocationManager.delegate and it forwards delegate messages. The Wrapper can change delegate without problem.